# I would like to return the current week as an array of dates using Javascript/Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to return an array of dates. Similar to the below.

I would like to have an array of 1 week periods in days, paginating 7 days at a time, with 'next week' and 'previous week' buttons.

I would ideally like it to be plain JavaScript

[choicechips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkl2R.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example is important to use the computed property, because you can change the week (next week or prior).

Try something like that:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="priorWeek">Prior Week</button>
      <span v-for="day in days" class="day">
        {{ day.toLocaleDateString() }}
      </span>
      <button @click="nextWeek">Next Week</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    first: new Date(),
  }),
  computed: {
    days() {
      return [
        this.first,
        this.addDays(this.first, 1),
        this.addDays(this.first, 2),
        this.addDays(this.first, 3),
        this.addDays(this.first, 4),
        this.addDays(this.first, 5),
        this.addDays(this.first, 6),
      ];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addDays(date, days) {
      let newDate = new Date(date);
      newDate.setDate(this.first.getDate() + days);
      return newDate;
    },
    subtractDays(date, days) {
      let newDate = new Date(date);
      newDate.setDate(this.first.getDate() - days);
      return newDate;
    },
    nextWeek() {
      this.first = this.addDays(this.first, 7);
    },
    priorWeek() {
      this.first = this.subtractDays(this.first, 7);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.day {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: purple;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Don't use this. Moment is deprecated and it shouldn't be anymore.
c.f : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: @Misha I didn't know about it. I rewrote my example with native Date object. Thanks for warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use js Date to get the current day and then based on that, you can use get the first and last date.

refer the example below:

```
let day = new Date().getDay() // for monday, it will give us 1 

let startDate = new Date().getDay() - day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // day * hours * minutes * seconds * milliseconds

let endDate = new Date(startDate) + 7  * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 7 days
```

after that, you can easily get the dates in this range

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that by starting with an array of today's date and then add a day for each position in the array. What kind of date library you use for this doesn't really matter, you can do it in vanilla JS without any library:

```js
const dates = new Array(5) // start with an empty array
  .fill(new Date())        // fill in today's date everywhere
  // finally, add some time based on the position of each element
  // getTime is in milliseconds, so we need to do some multiplication
  .map((dt, i) => new Date(dt.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * i))
```

and the idea would be the same for moment for example:

```js
const dates = new Array(5)
  .fill(moment()) // fill with moment's this time
  // adding time to a date is more convenient in moment
  .map((m, i) => m.clone().add(i, 'days'))
```